# camera1394stereo missing nodes on indigo

Tags: ros, bumblebee2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.1. I'm trying to use the camera1394stereo package with a Bumblebee2 to calibrate the camera. So far I have been able to git clone the most recent package (https://github.com/srv/camera1394stereo), build it, and roslaunch the stereo_camera_full.launch to get the correct topics to run camera_calibration. Unfortunately the calibration keeps failing in this case. I'm wondering if it's my manually built camera1394stereo node that's causing the failure. The problems I see are:

1. When I source my workspace instead of the ROS indigo workspace to run camera1394stereo's node, the reconfigure node (i.e dynamic_reconfigure or rqt_reconfigure) is not available unless I get that too which seems unnecessary.
2. I can "sudo apt-get install camera1394stereo" but there is no source, no executable nodes, and not as many launch files as the git repository.

What's wrong with my camera1394stereo by using "sudo apt-get install camera1394stereo"? Why does it not seem to be "complete"?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218569/camera1394stereo-missing-nodes-on-indigo/) by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2015-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> 2 . I can "sudo apt-get install camera1394stereo" but there is no source, no executable nodes, and not as many launch files as the git repository.

I don't really understand how this could've gone unnoticed for so long, but looking at the `CMakeLists.txt` of `camera1394stereo` ([here](https://github.com/srv/camera1394stereo/blob/c8ffe0e97c29d511491b19befb17ea2ecc5fed4d/CMakeLists.txt)), it seems it is missing the necessary `install(..)` statements.

This would cause the package to build fine on the farm, but no files would end up in the `.deb` that you install when you execute `sudo apt-get install ..`. The jenkins log for the [latest build](http://jenkins.ros.org/job/ros-indigo-camera1394stereo_binarydeb_trusty_i386/26/consoleText) seems to confirm this as well (search for `Install the project`): only files generated for `dynamic_reconfigure` and some other (meta data) files get installed, but no binaries or headers, as you observed.

I recommend you open an issue at the `camera1394stereo` [issue tracker](https://github.com/srv/camera1394stereo/issues) so the author / maintainer can fix this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2015-10-02**:
Thanks for the quick answer. Seems reasonable and I have opened an issue. Let's see what they say.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-03**:
In the meantime you could perhaps use the [GAVLab/camera1394stereo](https://github.com/GAVLab/camera1394stereo/tree/fhwa3) fork, which does have `install` statements.

**Comment by [jeremya](https://answers.ros.org/users/23980/jeremya/) on 2015-10-05**:
That's a good idea. I'll have to review the deltas.

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2015-10-28**:
Hi! I'm the maintainer of camera1394stereo. There's a new release with the install targets, and the issue is now closed.